# Dynamic ~/.ssh/config

Tags: bash, ssh, files, stdout

I'd like make my `~/.ssh/config` file dynamically generated by a shell script (or anything else that prints to STDOUT).

Is there a UNIX trick to make reading a file result in executing a command & reading it's STDOUT?

What I'd like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"

$ cat myfile
Hello World
```

Comment: This would only possible be possible with a self-written filesystem, e.g. via [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), or depending on the ssh implementation with FIFOs. Maybe the `-F` flag of ssh which allows to pass an alternative user-config file helps you. You can also replace ssh with an wrapper script, which sets the config file before running the actual ssh.

Comment: A colleague sent me this: https://github.com/markhellewell/sshconfigfs (which is an implementation of the FUSE idea)

Comment: This smells like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you explained why you want to do such a thing, there's a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Having a read of a file, trigger an execution of a program, can be dangerous. The execution would have to be done by the user that set it up, not the user that read the file. The program would therefore not have access to anything that the creator would not otherwise have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The true question is: Why do you need dynamic configuration (and thus how to avoid having to generate configuration dynamically).

> Is there a UNIX trick to make reading a file result in executing a command & reading it's STDOUT?

Bash has a feature that does exactly that, it's named "Process Substitution" :

```
ssh -F <( echo "Host *"; echo " User dummy" ) ssh.example.com
```

Unfortunately, **it won't work with openssh's ssh**, as it dies with error:

`Can't open user config file /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

Also, some people seems to use complex scheme to use a FIFO file, like [Multiple SSH client configuration files](http://www.linuxsysadmintutorials.com/multiple-ssh-client-configuration-files/), but eventually they use an alias, and that can be simplified with something like :

```
alias ssh = '~/bin/gen_ssh_config.sh > /tmp/XX; ssh -F /tmp/XX'
```

Comment: If you use `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can use the `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses temp files instead of pipes and /dev/fd: `ssh -F =(echo "Host *"; echo " User dummy") ssh.example.com`